# SQL and PHP brief explain

Tags: php, sql

```
$id=$_GET['previd'];
$SQL = "select * from pro where prId=".$id;
```

I am new to PHP. Can anyone explain what happens here?

Comment: I'm restraining myself.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: You make an sql injection, thats what happens here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is taking the value of the GET (url) passed variable "previd".
  Something like `http://example.com/page.php?previd=123` would set
  previd to 123.
- Next it sets the variable $id to 123.
- Next $SQL gets set to `select * from pro where prId=123`
- Next a nefarious person can go to `http://example.com/page.php?previd=;DROP TABLE pro` and your database has now been deleted.

This is why people use sanitization and prepared statements.

```
// PDO + MySQL
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT some_field FROM some_table");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['some_field']);
```

[More Info](http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension)

Comment: It would be very worrying indeed if `DROP TABLE` statements dropped an entire database!

Comment: My bad, the table gets deleted, haha.

Comment: Heh, NP. It's worth bearing in mind that whilst SQL injection vulns should be avoided, the multiple statement execution variant is rare because it is either not supported (mysql_) or needs special handling (mysqli). However, query modification is still a risk, for all libraries.